# cannot make an input in atom fro python

Tags: python

I am new to atom and python in general. 
I was able to print hello world in atom using python, but I cannot do the program of calculating the circle's area.

Here is what I get. I can do this in IDLE, but I do not know why I cannot input a radius here. Can anyone tell me how to solve it? Thank you!

(I have already saved the file)
[image: 1]

Comment: You need to use a terminal to run your program. Atom is a *text editor*, not an IDE. Although, you can install extensions that can make it function like an IDE.

Comment: I have already installed "script", which allows atom to run the code, and I have successfully used atom to run hello world.

Comment: [Atom will not allow you to use the `input()` function in python](https://discuss.atom.io/t/execute-python-scripts-with-input/25667). I forgot exactly why, but just run the file from the command line instead. Atom is really more of a "web IDE"(if it can be called an IDE at all).

Comment: @ChristianDean  what is the command line?

Comment: @R.T. The command line or terminal, is a basic text interface for your computer. It allows you to input commands to your OS, and see the output(if any) that running those commands produce. If you've ever used a REPL, then it is similar in concept. If you new to the command line, I suggest taking a [basic tutorial to familiarize yourself with it](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-the-command-line/lessons/navigation/exercises/your-first-command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script` cannot run `input` command, you have to use terminal to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue
if you use atom-python-run instead of script it works